# Feedjira gem does not work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, feedjira

I am using the Feedjira gem on Rails 4 to display feeds on my web application. Currently it is working locally, however when I push the application to Heroku for production I get a blank page with no feeds.

I have researched online but I have not found a working solution, does anyone know how to fix this?